# HVAC is heating when thermostat is off

Tags: hvac, thermostat

I seem to have a problem with my thermostat. I have tested the wiring of my HVAC system by wire nutting the the power (R, red wire) to the AC (Y, black wire), heat (W, white wire), and fan (G, green wire) to test their respective functions. They all turned on when connected and off shortly after being disconnected. However, when wiring up my new thermostat per the installation instructions, my furnace turns ON when the thermostat mode is set to off. Even if I plug the unit in with the mode set to off, the furnace immediately kicks on. The description of the wiring terminal designations for the thermostat match the description of my 5-wire HVAC unit, so I'm at a loss as to what I could have done wrong.

Because my thermostat has batteries, it is my understanding that the 24v common wire is not needed, but it is currently attached.

The model of thermostat is a Honeywell TH6210U2001.  The furnace control board is a Tempstar CEBD431004-23A.

Here is the wiring on the thermostat end: [image: Thermostat wiring]

Here is the wiring on the furnace end. The thermostat comes in from the left, while the bottom wires go out to the evaporator: [image: Furnace wiring]

Here is the description of the terminals from the thermostat installation instructions: [image: Instructions]

Is there a way that I can test the pins on the thermostat with a multimeter?  Is it possible that this thermostat is not compatible with my HVAC unit?

Comment: "Because my thermostat has batteries, it is my understanding that the 24v common wire is not needed, but it is currently attached.".                       The battery is not there to power your system, but gives power to run your thermostat display. You still need the 24v common wire...

Comment: You don't have a heat pump by any chance, do you?

Comment: @Huesmann No, no heat pump.

Comment: @NathanVanDyken so, if I understand the problem, the system is on, and blowing hot air when you change the mode to OFF (rather than AUTO, HEAT, COOL, or EM HEAT)?  And the air is hotter than the ambient outside temperature?  What happens on COOL or HEAT?

Comment: @Huesmann I am positive that it is heating when set to OFF; I can hear the propane furnace ignite and run.  When the mode is set to HEAT and COOL, it heats and cools as I would expect.

Comment: So you get cool on COOL, and heat on both HEAT and OFF?

Comment: @Huesmann That is correct.

Comment: Just spitballing here—have you tried the red wire in the Rc terminal?